# Convert hhmms to hh in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that has value in format hhmm eg :1243. I need to take hh from that column(i,e 12). Please advise
Column format of hhmm is int

Comment: `df['col']//100`?

Comment: if it's a string, then use `df['col'].str[:2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column has Timestamp or Datetime like values, then use the `.hour` method.

```
import pandas
dr = pandas.date_range('2017-01-01T11:30:00Z', '2017-02-01T11:30:00Z', freq='D')
data = pandas.Series(range(len(dr), index=dr)
data.index.map(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Or if you have a DataFrame:

```
df['times'] = df['times'].map(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column is `int`, the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['hhmm_format'] = [1243, 1151, 1211]

df['hh_only'] = df['hhmm_format'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:2])

df

hhmm_format hh_only
0   1243    12
1   1151    11
2   1211    12
```

If you need to convert back:

```
df.hh_only = pd.to_numeric(df.hh_only)
```